# Is it possible to plot the set(More than two) of lat and long values(History) on Google map via intent on android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, latitude-longitude

I am working on a application having a requirement to show the history on Google map. Without invoking Google map view, Is it possible to show the history on Google map by calling the Google map intent. 
I will be having a set(More than two) of lat and long values to plot on Google map.

I have searched in the internet. I found a way to plot two point on Google map that is source and destination. Please help me to plot the history on Google map.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check around By the help of Google Map intent we can plot only two points that is source and destination. There is no option to plot the History by giving more than two points.

The code to plot the two point in a map by the help of calling an map intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```